# Retag [visual-studio-setup] and [visual-studio-setup-proje]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

[visual-studio-setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-setup)  and [visual-studio-setup-proje](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-setup-proje) should be retagged.

Either we create a new tag [vs-setup-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vs-setup-project) or we retag to a combination of the existing [visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio) and [setup-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/setup-project) tags. I'm not sure which is the preferred way.

Comment: What is wrong with [visual-studio-setup]? Why would [vs-setup-project] be better?

Comment: @CodyGray [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307353) uses the term *Setup project*. [tag:visual-studio-setup] could be considered ambiguous too, is it about the setup of VS or is it about a setup project created with VS?

Comment: They used that terminology *years* ago, it is long obsolete. Visual Studio is now bundled with InstallShield LE. If anything, that would be a more appropriate tag.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm honestly not all that familiar with the subject, the last installer project I created was a couple of years ago. Feel free to post that as an answer :)

Comment: Setup projects were unfortunately reintroduced through add-ins.